# using useState inside a non react component - no error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I am not sure why this code works. Can someone explain?

File name : test.tsx

```
import { useState } from "react";

export const getComponents = () => {
  const hello = [].map(() => {
    const [state] = useState(0);
    return {
      b: "hello",
      d: <div>{state}</div>,
    };
  });
  return hello;
};
```

getComponents is not a React.isValidElement. Why am I able to use useState inside this function?

Codesandbox example : https://codesandbox.io/p/live/7f832aa1-c029-4083-98dd-c0068c502bc5

I would expect eslint to give me an error : "“react hooks must be called in a react function component or a custom react hook function”."

Comment: Why would eslint think `getComponents` is not a custom hook?

Comment: @Schleis custom hooks should always start with "use"?

Comment: does your eslint have the hooks plugin installed?

Comment: yep, it complains if I add the useState outside of map and directly after the getComponents initialization

Comment: using it inside the map method wont work as its not a react hook or component, you need to find a way to move it directly into your getComponents method, maybe using a reducer for each line item.

Comment: Sandbox link is 404, but React likely doesn't complain about the `useState` hook call because you are mapping from an empty array so the map callback is never called. I'm sure if you uses a populated array you'd see some generated errors about breaking the [Rules of Hooks](https://react.dev/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning#breaking-rules-of-hooks), specifically "Do not call Hooks inside conditions or ***loops***." It's not clear what you are trying do accomplish here, but `getComponents` is neither a React component nor a custom hook, so `useState` can't be called.